# How to write and in one Compare in GOSU

Tags: gosu

I have a query below and need to combine the 2nd and 3rd .compare condition with 'AND' operator

```
var query = ii.join(InvoiceItem#PolicyPeriod)
        .compare(PolicyPeriod#Plan, Relop.NotEquals, xyzPlan)
        .compareIn(PolicyPeriod#ProdType, {Prod.TC_FREE, Prod.TC_UNIQ})
        .compareIn(PolicyPeriod#Elig,{OffElig.TC_Yes})
```

Second compareIn statement should be like below in SQL but do not know how to combine two variables in one compare with  AND operator.

```
if ( prodtype in ('FREE','UNIQ') and Elig = 'YES')

Any Advice!!
```

Comment: Can you explain query that needs in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.and()` method from the QueryAPI:

```
var query = ii.join(InvoiceItem#PolicyPeriod)
    .compare(PolicyPeriod#Plan, Relop.NotEquals, xyzPlan)
    .and(\and1 -> {
        and1.compareIn(PolicyPeriod#ProdType, {Prod.TC_FREE, Prod.TC_UNIQ})
        and1.compareIn(PolicyPeriod#Elig, {OffElig.TC_Yes})
    })
```

In the same manner, you can use `.or()` method or even combine `and()` and `or()` in one statement.